# Basis for $\mathbb{[Q(\pi):Q]}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, rational-functions

I'm trying to figure out whether the basis of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable when $x$ is transcendental. I know that the elements in $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ will be rational functions in $x$ and so they are countable like algebraic numbers.

> Let the rank be the sum of coefficients and degrees of polynomials in denominator and numerator.

So it passes the necessary condition for countable basis outlined by Asaf Karagila in [Countable/uncountable basis of vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91878/50955). I have no more ideas to go with.

Edit:

Obviously a basis will have to be countable if the space is countable. So how do I go about finding a basis?

Comment: If there were an uncountable basis, how many distinct elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ would there be?

Comment: So, which part is your question.   (1) $\mathbb Q(\pi)$ is countable, or (2) if $K \supset \mathbb Q$ is countable, then the dimension of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$ is (at most) coutable...

Comment: I'm trying to find a basis for it.

Comment: Perhaps you can think of "partial fractions" to find a basis.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126747

Comment: Possible duplicate of [k-basis for k(X)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126747/k-basis-for-kx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer my own question using the suggestion by GEdgar in the comments. $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a Euclidean Domain and by the theorem of [Partial Fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction#cite_note-1)

> Let $f$ and $g$ be nonzero polynomials over a field $K$. Write $g$ as a product of powers of distinct irreducible polynomials :
>
> $$g=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{n_i}$$
>
> There are (unique) polynomials $b$ and $a_{ij}$ with $\deg(a_{ij})<\deg(p_i)$ such that
>
> $$\frac{f}{g}=b+\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\frac{a_{ij}}{p_i^j}$$
>
> If $\deg(f)<\deg(g)$, then $b=0$.

Let $$\mathcal{B}_1=\{x^n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ and $$\mathcal{B}_2=\left\{\dfrac{x^n}{p^m} : p \text{ is a monic irreducible and } 0\le n < \deg(p)\right\}.$$

The theorem implies $\cal B_1 \cup B_2$ is a basis for $\mathbb Q(x)$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: This is how this forum can work.  We give some hints, and the inquirer finds a solution.